# Test-Path issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012

Why does `Test-Path -Path $folder -PathType Container` return `true`, but folder does not exist?
The Path is:

> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MyCompany\Modules

**Same code in ISE x86 and ISE, but different results**

[image]

[image]

Comment: So is system32 cloaked or hidden in a 64 bit process even if you have an explicit full path?   My powershell stuff has always been in C:\Windows\SysWOW64   only.  So I would have always had the opposite result you are having.

Comment: Yes, the folder is under `SysWow64` But why does the ISE x86 console show true and the ISE console false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is [here](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)

Excerpt:

> **The 'System32' folder is for 64-bit files and the 'SysWOW64' folder is for 32-bit files**
>
> This can be somewhat confusing, but the System32 folder is intended
>   for 64-bit files and the SysWOW64 folder is intended for 32-bit files.
>
> This may seem a bit illogical if you look at the folder names, but
>   there is an explanation to this. It has to do with compatibility. Many
>   developers have hard coded the path to the system folder in their
>   applications source code. They have included "System32" in the folder
>   path. And to preserve compatibility, if the application is converted
>   to 64-bit code, the 64-bit system folder is still named System32.
>
> But what about 32-bit applications that have the system path hard
>   coded and is running in a 64-bit Windows? How can they find the new
>   SysWOW64 folder without changes in the program code, you might think.
>
> The answer is that the emulator redirects calls to System32 folder to
>   the SysWOW64 folder transparently so even if the folder is hard coded
>   to the System32 folder (like C:\Windows\System32), the emulator will
>   make sure that the SysWOW64 folder is used instead. So same source
>   code, that contains a path with the System32 folder included, can be
>   compiled to both 32-bit and 64-bit program code without any changes.
>
> So remember:   • the SysWOW64 folder is intended for 32-bit files only
>   • the System32 folder is intended for 64-bit files only   It is very
>   important that a binary file compiled to a specific bitness (32 or 64)
>   is installed to the correct system folder. Otherwise the program that
>   needs the file will not be able to load the file and will probably not
>   work as expected.

That's why ISE x86 output is in SysWow64 folder and the call to:

> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MyCompany\Modules

is redirected to the SysWow64 folder.

The ISE console is running as x64 and therefore will look in System 32 and will not find this folder, but the folder was created in ISE x86 console, which saves the folder under SysWOW64.